# jQuery Slugify Not Work with Utf-8 characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, unicode, utf-8

I work in arabic project and need to slugify input url using jQuery [slugify](https://github.com/pmcelhaney/jQuery-Slugify-Plugin) plugin But This plugin not support Unicode Utf-8 characters Like This :

[image]

HTML :

```
<div>
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="title" value="" id="title" size="60" class="form-control">
</div>
<div>
    <label for="slug_input">Slug</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="slug" id="slug_input" value="" class="slug form-control" size="60">
</div>
```

JS:

```
$().ready(function () {
    $('.slug').slugify('#title');

    var pigLatin = function (str) {
        return str.replace(/(\w*)([aeiou]\w*)/g, "$2$1ay");
    }

    $('#pig_latin').slugify('#title', {
        slugFunc: function (str, originalFunc) {
            return pigLatin(originalFunc(str));
        }
    });

});
```

how do can fix this for utf-8 characters Or any plugin and example for slug utf-8 input url using jQuery?!

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j6dehcvp/)